# rails 4: cannot load such file -- sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to use bootstrap in my project. My operating system is Windows, Ruby version is 1.9.3, Rails version 4.0.4.

I try to bundle one gem every time because there is dependence in some gem when I execute bundle install.

```
bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.0)
sass (3.3.5, 3.2.19)
sass-rails (4.0.2)
sprockets (2.12.0, 2.11.0)
```

Now, I add `//= require bootstrap` into `application.js` and add `@import "bootstrap"` into `application.css.scss`. But when I start server, I got `Load Error in *Controller#home`:

```
cannot load such file -- sass (in D:/first_app/app/assets/style sheets / application.css.scss
```

Extracted source (around line #5):

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

```
Rails.root: D:/rails_projects/first_app
```

Any advice?

Comment: add the necessary gems in Gemfile and run bundle install. that way bundler will check for dependencies and handle conflicting dependencies too.

Answer (score 4):

Did you make sure that you also removed the sprockets `//= require` directive in your `application.css.scss` file?

Also, make sure all your gem versions are aligned. According to this [rubygems page](http://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass/versions/2.3.2.0), version 2.3.2 of `boostrap-rails` requires version 3.1 for the `saas` gem. Running `bundle install` should also notify you of any gem version mismatches in your `Gemfile`.

Finally, if you're using Rails 4, why are you using an older version of `bootstrap-rails`? The [latest stable version](http://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass/versions) of `bootstrap-rails` is 3.1.1.0 (as of Feb 13, 2014).